# Etherscan fetching wrong parameter name in input data information table?

Tags: solidity, etherscan

The information table (bottom of a tx page) in Etherscan shows one of the parameters' name of a function call is "_foo", while I cannot find any reference *anywhere* in the codebase (including JSON ABIs, events) to a parameters called "_foo".

How is this possible? Where does Etherscan fetch the name of these parameters from?

Comment: Please share link to the transaction on Etherscan (and the actual parameter name).

Comment: This contract https://ftmscan.com/address/0xa00b534fec817bd5e4f9a10ed1c31fe6de087df9 is a factory-generated contract. The clone code is available in creator contract. 
A `deposit` transaction shows a parameter `_pid` that is nowhere to be found in the the factory code (and anywhere else in the code and ABIs). I can confirm that this `_pid` parameter is also there if you redeploy the protocol contracts.